# sed: search for a pattern after a particular line containing a keyword

Tags: parsing, sed

input file:

```
new file
myString
abc
myString
xyz
pattern
file txt
myString
almost the end of file
myString
end of file
```

The input file contains multiple occurrences of `myString` throughout the entire file but I need to replace only the first occurrence of `myString` that occurs after another pattern `pattern`.

Also, there are no specific number of lines between `pattern` and first occurrence of `myString`.

desired output:

```
new file
myString
abc
myString
xyz
pattern
file txt
replacement_pattern
almost the end of file
myString
end of file
```

I want to do this task using `sed`, if possible

Comment: Did you try reading an introduction to `sed`?

Comment: @tripleee I already did a lot of research over this before asking here... but nothing is working out for me

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee sorry i am relatively new to this platform.. still learning every day. it would be great if you could also help me out with my query.

Comment: It would be great if you tried the advice in my first comment. What you are asking is not hard to do once you learn the basics (though not entirely trivial), and explaining them to you in an answer would be tedious when the Internet is full of existing introductions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/{:a;N;s/myString/myReplacement/;Ta}' file
```

Gather up lines after finding one that contains `pattern` and replace the first match with a replacement string.

Alternative:

```
sed '/pattern/{:a;n;/myString/!ba;s//myReplacement/}' file
```

Same idea but using traditional sed commands rather that GNU specific.

N.B. This solution uses `n` instead of `N` which may affect the speed of the result (as it uses the implicit print for each line that is not matched by `myString`) in contrast to using less memory and printing all lines once a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The simple would be just:

```
/pattern/,/myString/s/myString/replacement_pattern/
```

For the first *and only first* myString in file I think there should be something simple, but I ended up with:

```
/pattern/,${ x; /myString/!{ x; //{ h; s//replacement_pattern/}; x}; x}'
```

A bit shorter:

```
/pattern/,${ /myString/{ x; //!{ g; s//replacement_pattern/; x}; x} }
```